# Is it possible to pipe multiple commands in an 'if' statement?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Part of a script I'm writing needs to check various text files for the same strings. Before I just had to check one file so I had a long list of strings within cateogies to search for which are defined as variables. Later on in the script the variabled are called and output to the screen if there is a match:

```
category_1=$(sudo zcat myfile | egrep -c 'Event 1|Event 2|Event 3')

category_2=$(sudo zcat myfile | egrep -c 'Event 4|Event 5|Event 6')

category_3=$(sudo zcat myfile | egrep -c 'Event 7|Event 8|Event 9')

...

echo Category 1

if [[ $category_1 -ge 2 ]];then

            echo There were $category_1 events

elif [[ $category_1 -eq 1 ]]; then

            echo There was $category_1 event

fi
```

etc, etc...

Now I need to change it so that I can check the grepped strings against multiple text files. I've tried to define the new files as variables and pipe them in the if statement with the grep variable to no avail:

```
category_1=$(egrep -c 'Event 1|Event 2|Event 3')

category_2=$(egrep -c 'Event 4|Event 5|Event 6')

category_3=$(egrep -c 'Event 7|Event 8|Event 9')


myfile=$(sudo zcat myfile)

myfile2=$(sudo zcat myfile2)

myfile3=$(sudo zcat myfile3)

...

echo Category 1 - Myfile



if [[ myfile | $category_1 -ge 2 ]];then

            echo There were $category_1 events in myfile

elif [[ myfile | $category_1 -eq 1 ]]; then

            echo There was $category_1 event in myfile

fi
```

It seems that I can't pipe commands in an if statement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `$(...)` to capture output of a command into a string:

```
if  [[ $(sudo zcat myfile1 | egrep -c 'Event 1|Event 2|Event 3') -ge 2 ]] ; then
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the 'egrep' command set as a variable so that I don't have to put 'Event 1' etc, in each command? So it would be more like
grepvariable1=$egrep -c 'Event 1|Event 2|Event 3'if [[ $(sudo zcat myfile1 | grepvariable1) -ge 2 ]]; then

Comment: @Hxwk: You can define a function that contains the code you want to repeat.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll look into functions

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipes in `if`, but you mix two things.
You use `$category_1` with pipe; and `$category_1` is not a command.
You can use a command substitution instead of the variable.

```
if [[ `sudo zcat myfile | egrep -c 'Event 1|Event 2|Event 3')` -ge 2 ]];then
```

and so on.

You can also use variables instead of commands, but it will be a little bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use a command such as: if [ "$house" = "nice" ]||[ "$house" = "bad" ] then... to do the job

Comment: This would be much more useful if you explained how it works and what it does, also please read the [help] pages about formatting answers.